# Unable to build JAR file for my maven PARENT prroject

Tags: java, git, maven, selenium, release

I have created two training projects aiming to the creation of a Java Test Automation Framework with Selenium.

Both projects have been stored in my personal git: https://github.com/omarjmc

Framework: Contains main classes and all the code needed to execute successfuly the tests

Project: Demo project that will use the methods specified in the Framework project

Additionally i added the dependency to the Framework project in the demo Project's POM and I also created a release of the Framework project and attached the JAR file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FekgU.png)

Currently I have to clone both repositories and run mvn clean install on the framework to get the JAR file and change the packaging back to pom, but I want to just clone the demo project, run mvn clean install there and still get the Framework JAR file.

What am I missing the POM file?

Answer (score 0):

Omar you have to create a maven multi module project for this requirement. Project will be the parent project and it should contain framework as child.

The basic code structure for pom.xml for Project should be like this.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>multi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>project</name>
    <modules>
        <module>framework</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

You can refer below the github project for this exact requirement.

https://github.com/jamesward/maven-multi-module-example

Comment: Can it be done with JitPack? or multi module is the only way to achieve what i'm trying?

Answer (score 0):

I created a multi-module proyect, but it only works if you download the original repository, what I want is to have them in separate repositories and just download, and use, the project child